# How to create multiple Subnets in pre-existing Vnet Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, networking, azure-runbook

I have the following code which works good for adding a few subnets but I would like for this script to leverage a CSV file to import from and add the subnets into a pre-existing Vnet?

```
$appssubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name servers -AddressPrefix "172.16.1.0/24" -NetworkSecurityGroupId "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/powershell-grp/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/app-nsg1"`
-RouteTableId "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/powershell-grp/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/powershell-rt"
$serversubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name apps -AddressPrefix "172.16.2.0/24" -RouteTableId "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/powershell-grp/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/powershell-rt"
$dmz = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name dmz -AddressPrefix "172.16.3.0/24"
$updatedvnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "testsubnet" -ResourceGroupName "powershell-grp" -Location "North Europe" -AddressPrefix "172.16.0.0/16" -Subnet $serversubnet, $dmz, $appssubnet -Force:$true
$updatedvnet | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use the below powershell script.***

```
  $subnets1 = Import-Csv "C:\Users\v-XXXsXX18\Documents\TestCount.csv"
    #$subnets1.subnetName
    foreach ($subnet in $subnets1){
    $dmz = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnet.SubnetName -AddressPrefix $subnet.AddressPrefix
    
    $vnet=Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "MyVirtualNetworkTes" -ResourceGroupName "v-raXXXXndtree"
    $updatedvnet=Add-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $dmz.Name -VirtualNetwork $vnet -AddressPrefix $dmz.AddressPrefix
    
    $updatedvnet | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
    
    
    }
```

[image]

Output--

[image]

[image]